# Ng generate in specified location doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a problem generating components in my Angular 2 application. I'm running the command `ng g component [nameofcomponent] -it -is` in a folder named 'other'. According to the documentation it should generate the component inside this folder, not outside. I don't know why it's happening.

[image: this image]

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/Mi0XX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay seems like it was error when i was using git bash instead of cmd.
In cmd everything works fine. I dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine.

```
M74-MAC:~/App_v2/src/app/other$ ng g component new-component
installing component
  create src/app/other/new-component/new-component.component.css
  create src/app/other/new-component/new-component.component.html
  create src/app/other/new-component/new-component.component.spec.ts
  create src/app/other/new-component/new-component.component.ts
```